# How to use tasks, background threads or another method to solve a hanging issue in Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-services

I was wondering the best way to get round this issue.

I have created a Windows Service that connects to a mailbox, processes the emails, then cleans up after itself, waits a certain amount of time and repeats.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this._mainTask = new Task(this.Poll, this._cancellationToken.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    this._mainTask.Start();
}

private void Poll()
{
    CancellationToken cancellation = this._cancellationToken.Token;
    TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.Zero;

    while (!cancellation.WaitHandle.WaitOne(interval))
    {
        using (IImapClient emailClient = new S22ImapClient())
        {
            ImapClientSettings chatSettings = ...;

            emailClient.Connect(chatSettings); // CAN SOMETIMES HANG HERE

            // SOME WORK DONE HERE
        }

        interval = this._waitAfterSuccessInterval;

        // check the cancellation state.
        if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am using a 3rd party IMAP client "S22.Imap". When I create the email client object on occasion it will hang on creation as it is attempting to login. This in turn will hang my Windows Service indefinitely.

```
public class S22ImapClient : IImapClient
{
    private ImapClient _client;

    public void Connect(ImapClientSettings imapClientSettings)
    {
        this._client = new ImapClient(
            imapClientSettings.Host,
            imapClientSettings.Port,
            imapClientSettings.EmailAddress,
            imapClientSettings.Password,
            AuthMethod.Login,
            true);
    }
}
```

How would I change the "S22ImapClient.Connect()" call to, behind the covers, use some method to attempt to connect for a set amount of time, then abort if it has not been able to?

The solution to this will also be used for anything that I need to do with the mail client, for example "GetMessage()", "DeleteMessage()" etc

Comment: *When I create the email client object on occasion it will hang on creation as it is attempting to login* Is that behavior documented? If not, file a bug or stop using that third party.

Comment: I haven't seen it documented anywhere. I actually expected some sort of "BeginConnect", "EndConnect" functionality. I had a look at MailDll as well, and that appears to work similar to this as far as I can tell, no "Begin", "End"

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I took your advice and moved to another 3rd party component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stop using the S22.Imap email client for this particular problem, and use another 3rd party component, ActiveUp MailSystem, as it includes async calls out the box.

This way I can do code like this:

```
IAsyncResult connectResult = this._client.BeginConnectSsl(imapClientSettings.Host, imapClientSettings.Port, null);

if (!connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(this._connectionTimeout))
{
    throw new EmailTimeoutException(this._connectionTimeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cancellation token source and give it a time to cancel after in the event that it hangs too long. Otherwise you would just have to extend the third party class and implement an async version of the Connect method. This is untested but should give you the basic idea.

```
private void Poll()
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.Zero;

    while (!source.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(interval))
    {
        using (IImapClient emailClient = new S22ImapClient())
        {
            ImapClientSettings chatSettings = ...;

            var task = Task.Run(() => 
            {
                source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                emailClient.Connect(chatSettings); // CAN SOMETIMES HANG HERE                   
            }, source.Token);

            // SOME WORK DONE HERE
        }

        interval = this._waitAfterSuccessInterval;

        // check the cancellation state.
        if (source.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely in your code, it would hang on "emailClient.Connect()" and never reach the "source.CancelAfter()"? Also, the "Task.Run", is it blocking? So that I could do more things once the connect is complete, but before the while loop continues with the next iteration?

Comment: You could move the CancelAfter above that line. The task.run is not blocking in this case but you could await it if you needed to or do the rest of the work in a continuation (ContinueWith()).

Comment: I have just typed this code in, you get a warning in Visual Studio "access to a disposed closure", with regards to the "emailClient" inside the "Task.Run"

Comment: Although, that may be because ReSharper isn't clever enough to realise that if I "await" that code, it will never be disposed at that point.